# how to use success message in view function along with withDeatils?

Tags: php, laravel-5

my return tag containing withhDetails and success message.. while return is perform the success msg is not printing and my code is below
controller:

```
public function listing($id)
{

    $data=Registration::where('id',$id)->get();      
    return view('search')->withDetails($data)->with('sucess','data updated');
}
```

view:

```
@if($message=Session::get('sucess'))
                                <div class="alert alert-sucess">
                                  <p>{{$message}}</p>
                                </div>
                              @endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing the data to the blade file then you can access it as below:

```
@if(isset($sucess) && $sucess != '')
    <div class="alert alert-sucess">
     <p>{{$sucess}}</p>
   </div>
@endif
```

There is no need to use session variable as you are not passing data to the session varible just use above code and you are good to access that variable in your blade file because you are just rendering the list file and not redirecting to any other URL.

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted and do up votes!!

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
//controller
return redirect(url('/user/' . $request->id))->with('success', 'success message');

//blade file
@if(session()->has('message'))
      <div class="alert alert-info fade show m-2" role="alert">
      <div class="alert-text"><strong>MESSAGE : </strong>{{ session()->get('message') }}</div>
      <div class="alert-close">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="la la-close"></i></span>
      </button>
      </div>
      </div>
      @endif
```